# python - matplotlib: How do I make the x-axis months regardless the year?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to overlay data from 2018, 2019, 2020 on top of each other but the years making the plots one after the other rather than overlayed. Here's the code I have right now:

```
locator = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
# Specify the format - %b gives us Jan, Feb...
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')

# Change size of plot to be longer on x axis
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.style.use('seaborn')

plt.plot(dfaqi2018['date'],dfaqi2018['co'],label=2018)
plt.plot(dfaqi2019['date'],dfaqi2019['co'],label=2019)
#plt.plot(dfaqi2020['co'],label=2020)

plt.legend()
X = plt.gca().xaxis
X.set_major_locator(locator)
# Specify formatter
X.set_major_formatter(fmt)
#plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Which gives this graph:
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq1mP.png)

How do I make the x axis Jan - Jan without having the years affecting the graph? Thanks!

Comment: Are the dates text or datetime objects? Try `plt.plot(dfaqi2018['date'].dt.month...`, and `...dfaqi2019['date'].dt.month...` [dt accessors](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html#datetimelike-properties)

Comment: They are datetime objects. I tried removing the years but that caused problems as well mainly because it wouldn't differentiate between Jan of one year and Jan of the next.